# buy token with card

Tags: ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Hi I'm new to developing dapps and I was wondering if there was a way to natively integrate credit card payments? I would like my users to be able to pay for my tokens/ether directly with their credit card. It'd be awesome to be able to target people who don't know anything about cryptocyrrencies ha.

Does anyone have a good way to do this or a good workaround solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out [www.connextapi.com](http://connextapi.com)

They're only a sandbox right now, but they should be processing credit card payments soon.

Answer (score 1):

Simply register yourself as a merchant with one of the payment providers like WorldPay or CyberSource, most of them provides a simple web interface to integrate with. Then let users pay for your tokens using the payment provider interface. Payment provider is going to notify you once the payment is done - you can then create an appropriate entry in your contract.

The issue with credit card payments is chargeback though - what do you do if you issue tokens and then you are charged back?